# How can I make an accompanist navigation BottomSheet fully expanded?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I know that a normal bottom sheet can be setup like this

```kotlin
rememberModalBottomSheetState(
  initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, 
  confirmStateChange = { it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded },
)
```

So that it will never be half expanded. But what if I want to do the same in Accompanist navigation with bottomsheets?

Comment: Hmm, nobody replied... You want me to start a bounty for you mama?

Comment: Thank you - I found the solution myself :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = true
)
val bottomSheetNavigator = remember { BottomSheetNavigator(sheetState) }
val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)
```

Instead of using `rememberBottomSheetNavigator()` you can just use the constructor of `BottomSheetNavigator` which takes a sheetstate which can be set with a simple boolean. :)

Comment: Omg, you are a life saver!